# Caching get_serving_url() URL

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Can I cache the url returned from `get_serving_url()`? How long until the url expire? I plan to add caching support to my application to reduce load.

Thank you very much for your response :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can cache it, as long as you keep a separate cache for each different `size` and `crop` value. The URL will only expire if you delete the Blob (although it may take up to 24 hours to effectively be deleted).

Source: [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/9525f68cbe04d165) (see response by Ikai L)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it and see how it goes.